# If my comment flag was declined, and I feel it was declined mistakenly, should I flag the comment again?

Tags: discussion, comments, declined-flags, comment-flags

The situation that prompted my question is [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600626/begins-with-in-twig-template/19919021#comment38411736_19919021) which I flagged for being "no longer needed" since the answer has since been edited with the comment's suggestion. But for some reason it was declined. I am unable to flag it as no longer needed. Therefore, should I flag it again using the "Something else" category and explain that the comment is obsolete?

Is there any detriment to myself if the system notices that I am flagging the same thing multiple times?

My reasoning for wanting to have this comment removed is because it states that the answer is incorrect, which is no longer the case.

Screenshot of comment:
[image]

Comment: I tend to flag on the assumption that the mod will only look at the flag and the comment itself (and not the post or other comments). In this case, you can't tell the comment should be removed based on those things, thus a custom flag with an explanation is necessary. Although "the post has been edited to address this" *should* be the most common use case for removing comments (because that's like the primary use case for comments), so this seems like a broken system. But maybe I'm just too sceptical about whether my comment will be declined.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Therefore, should I flag it again using the "Something else" category and explain that the comment is obsolete?

Yes. Sometimes moderators do make mistakes. The moderator that handled your flag probably didn't see the edit to the answer which made the comment obsolete.

Sometimes, while handling the comment flags in the queue, it is very easy to miss the perspective from which you would have seen the comment, therefore explaining it with a other flag would be the best. (the erstwhile obsolete comment flags were the most suitable here)

I've deleted that comment now.

> Is there any detriment to myself if the system notices that I am flagging the same thing multiple times?

No. It isn't an issue. (However, there is a restriction that you can't flag a NLN comment with a NLN flag again)

Comment: Quick follow-up question: since it is hard to notice the change to the answer, should I default to using the custom flag so I can give proper context? Or should I still do "no longer needed" first, then do the other flag if the first one is declined? I feel like I would have a better chance to have the comment removed if I use a custom flag with the proper context. Or would that be too much noise for moderators?

Comment: @KodosJohnson, default to using the custom flag when you think that it needs more context. It won't be noisy at all, and we'll have more information while handling the flag.

Comment: FWIW: I often prefix the custom comment with "No longer needed" followed by the explanation.  At least, that starts the moderator off with the right basic information/attitude towards the comment.

Comment: The default moderator approach to "No longer needed" should be to check the post history. That's the whole point of the flag.