# Why were my "no longer needed" flags on comments suggesting changes rejected (after the changes are made)?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

**tl;dr**: Should comments that suggest changes to answers (and are subsequently actioned) be flagged as "*no longer needed*"?

---

I recently had two declined comment flags on comments which suggested edits to answers which were actioned. I felt that they fell under the guidance on the form that appears:

> **It's no longer needed.**
>
> This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to this post.

In my mind the two cases were pretty clear-cut because as soon as the suggestions were actioned, they were no longer needed and counted as noise to the answer.

---

**Case 1**

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54548667/1364007) to [Python FizzBuzz Program - How to Get Number and String to Both Print](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54548643/1364007), [jrd1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/866930/jrd1) added [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548643/python-fizzbuzz-program-how-to-get-number-and-string-to-both-print/54548667#comment95897538_54548667):

> Not quite - this will print "3Fizz" if `num == 3`. You need a space somewhere

which was actioned less than a minute later, in [revision 2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54548667/2) of the answer - changing

```
string = string + "Fizz"
```

to

```
string = str(num)+ " " + "Fizz"
```

(i.e. adding a space).

---

**Case 2**

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54548597/1364007) to [Use of async await to do multiple db queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54548212/1364007), [Haris Bouchlis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3565132/haris-bouchlis) added [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548212/use-of-async-await-to-do-multiple-db-queries/54548597#comment95897611_54548597):

> I would suggest adding a try-catch block. Otherwise good answer.

which was actioned in [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54548597/3) of the answer, changing

> ```
> app.get('/shopdetails/:id', async function(req, res) {
>  const getData = await Shop.findOne({_id: req.params.id});
>  const getDataEmploye = await Employee.countDocuments({_shop: id});
>  const getDataProduct = await Product.countDocuments({_shop: id});
>  // after that, you will get respons from Shop and Employe collection. Check console.log(getData), console.log(getDataEmploye), console.log(getDataProduct)
>  //you can doing anything after get that collection data
>  });
> });
> ```

to

> ```
> app.get('/shopdetails/:id', async function(req, res) {
>   try{
>    const getData = await Shop.findOne({_id: req.params.id});
>    const getDataEmploye = await Employee.countDocuments({_shop: id});
>    const getDataProduct = await Product.countDocuments({_shop: id});
>    // after that, you will get respons from Shop and Employe collection. Check console.log(getData), console.log(getDataEmploye), console.log(getDataProduct)
>    //you can doing anything after get that collection data
>    } catch(err){
>     console.log(err)
>    }
>   });
> });
> ```

(i.e. adding a try-catch block).

---

Should I not have flagged these comments as being "no longer needed"?

Comment: Strange. These comments were handled rather inconsistently. Why would a comment by A suggesting an edit be kept but a reply acknowledging A's suggestion be deleted?

Comment: @BoltClock - Yeah, I had forgotten about the follow-up comments: in both cases (I think) I flagged comments by the answerer which said something along the lines of "thanks - edited". I can't remember for sure, but I think they were deleted instantly (so presumably passed the threshold for autodeletion).

Comment: Yeah, one of them did. The other was deleted manually.

Comment: **Yes**, Any comment requesting clarification or suggesting some changes in post  that has since been edited into the post than it can be flagged as **no longer needed**.

Comment: @NileshRathod: How moderator can make sure that the requested changes are reflected in post? Specially if moderator is not expert in said technology. So, I think easy way is to check if reply comment from post writer saying the modifications are done should present. Otherwise, it may be difficult to judge if changes are really reflected OR why comment is NLN in first place.

Comment: @AmitJoshi - Moderators [can see](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267888/1364007) deleted comments. Whether or not the deleted comments appear in the context when actually reviewing flags I don't know.

Comment: This is related to a question I asked a while ago: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373832/if-my-comment-flag-was-declined-and-i-feel-it-was-declined-mistakenly-should-i. Have you tried flagging them again and using the "something else" category?

Comment: @KodosJohnson - thanks for the link - I've linked it in my (edited) answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been a few days since I posted the question and I've had a chance to get some perspective on what happened. Clearly I can't speak for the moderator(s) who took the action to decline my flags, but I have since taken the time to do a bit more reading. I initially tried to change my flagging method, and have since had some (anonymous) feedback from a moderator through the flag feedback system. Following that I've changed my flagging method and, hopefully, will have fewer declined flags in future.

---

**1. Reading**

Some things that I've come across in the FAQ and that have been pointed out to me in comments here:

- The "*Flagging a comment*" section of the [Flagging help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging), which says (emphasis mine):

  > You must specify a reason for each comment flag. The most common cases are listed in the comment flag dialog box:
  >
  > - rude or abusive
  > - no longer needed - the comment is obsolete, chatty, or otherwise unnecessary
  > - in need of moderator intervention - A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator
  >
  > If you see a post where many comments should be deleted, especially if there's an ongoing discussion, **there’s no need to flag each comment. Flag the post for moderator attention, and use the “other” reason explain what's going on.**
- Also, in "[*Must I flag every comment as “too chatty”?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252456/1364007)", [BoltClock ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock) replied [with](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252458/1364007) (again, emphasis mine):

  > You can use a custom flag on the post containing the comments to explain to the moderators that the rest of the comments need scrubbing and not just the one that you would have otherwise flagged as too chatty.
  >
  > I hear work is being done to improve the workflow for moderators which should make this less necessary in the future. But **context always helps**, and we always appreciate when users include more details in their flags for us to work with.
- In a reply to "[*If my comment flag was declined, and I feel it was declined mistakenly, should I flag the comment again?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373832/1364007)", the [(accepted) reply](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373833/1364007) by [Bhargav Rao ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4099593/bhargav-rao) said that

  > Sometimes, while handling the comment flags in the queue, it is very easy to miss the perspective from which you would have seen the comment, therefore explaining it with a other flag would be the best. (the erstwhile obsolete comment flags were the most suitable here)
- In a reply to "[*Can the mods agree on how we should mass-flag comments?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338911/1364007)", the [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338934/1364007) by [deceze♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) said that

  > - When raising a custom flag, please be as direct as possible with what your concern is to avoid miscommunication.
  > - When something needs more discussion (e.g. was this merge warranted?), post on meta where a discussion can be had; flags are the wrong place to invite discussion.
  > - It is indeed cumbersome to flag a lot of individual comments, so yes, flagging a single comment or the post with a "some comments need deletion" is still fine.
  > - If you flag a comment directly, that comment shows up for moderators directly and can be dealt with in a single click. Raising a custom flag always requires more in-detail intervention and raises the risk of misunderstandings, or of mis-judgement. So again, custom flags should be very clear about what you need a moderator to do.

---

**2. Another declined comment flag**

I've since had another rejected comment flag on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54569070/1364007) by [Jack Bashford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10221765/jack-bashford) - the comment thread was

- > Thanks Jack. I had forgotten about pop(), that's helpful. And yes the use of 'Object' was really for my explanation, it's not used in my code ;-). – [BoDeX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/756458/bodex)
- > No problem @BoDex, I'm glad I could help. – [Jack Bashford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10221765/jack-bashford)

Trying to reduce the chance of a rejected comment I flagged the *second* comment, with the intention of going back and flagging the first comment if the second comment was deleted.

While this latest rejected comment flag doesn't fall within the scope of this question, it (and the quotes above) helps me to understand why the comments were rejected.

---

**3. Using custom flags in all instances - or not?**

Following my re-reading the FAQ, and the questions linked in the commments to this question/answer, I tried switching to custom flags *on the answers*, suggesting that the moderator deal with the flags rather than raising *individual flags* on the comments themselves. That way the moderator would at least get context.

This worked well for a while, but I *did* get some feedback on a custom flag that I raised on an accepted answer where there were two comments: (1) the OP thanking the answerer for their answer, and (2) the answerer asking the OP to accept their answer.

My custom flag,

> Both comments on this accepted answer are obsolete (thanks/request for acceptance).

was marked helpful but the moderator who dealt with it also added [a reply to the flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgIlE.png):

> Note: for just 2 or 3 comments, it is actually easier for us to just delete comments when flagged with comment flags. Flagging the post requires several more clicks to purge the comments.

---

**4. What I'll do from here**

Moving forwards I'll flag comments using the following system:

- Use standard no longer needed flags if there are fewer than four of them and:

  - the comments are 'chatty' or otherwise **don't add anything to the question/answer**, e.g. "*Great answer!*" or "*Thanks!*", or
  - the comments are obsolete, e.g. "*Please consider accepting my answer if you found it useful*" on accepted answers.
- Use a custom flag if:

  - there are four or more comments to delete (in which case it's presumably fewer clicks for a moderator to delete the comments), or
  - the reason that the comments are no longer needed isn't trivial, and the context from the post is required (e.g. in the cases of my rejected flags above).

Comment: I should point out that while I now have some insight into why the flags *might* have been rejected, I would still like some clarification on the matter. My intent here isn't to get an apology, or even to have the rejections reversed (though that would be nice) - I just want to know what to do in future instances.

Comment: I don't think that this is needed...I mean, that's the whole point of having "no longer needed" as a flag for comments

Comment: @Lamak - Sorry, I'm not following you: what does the "this" in your comment refer to?

Comment: the "I should have raised custom flags on the answers, suggesting that the moderator deal with the flags" part of your post

Comment: @Lamak - but if 'No longer needed' flags are sufficient when the comment is obsolete, what reason would there be for their rejection? As I was saying, I can only guess: I don't know - hence this question.

Comment: Relevant reading: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338911/1709587. Different mods (and sometimes the same mod at different times) have voiced different preferences on whether we should use a post flag or many comment flags to flag for deletion of an entire comment conversation. Given the lack of mod consensus, a flagger's choice of one approach or the other should never be taken as a justification for rejecting a flag.

Comment: @MarkAmery - thanks for the link. I got [some feedback from a moderator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgIlE.png) (I have no way of knowing who) which said that for just two or three comments, individual comment flags should suffice. I'm going to stick by that for now and see how that goes.

Comment: In lieu of another answer I'll accept my self-answer for now (permanently?).